# a weird thing when submit a form

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
  $("#edit-submit").click(function(){
    if($("#field-huima-0-value").val() == '' && $(".link-field .form-text").val() =='') {
      alert("you must at least enter one value！");
    //  return false;
    }
  });

});
```

**the jquery version is 1.26**  there are two input text box.  `field-huima-0-value` and `.link-field .form-text`.

i want to do: the vistor must be type into one text box and can't type into two input box.and if the vistor doesn't type anything,. then alert a window and prevent the form form submitting.

**weird thing** 
when i added the `return false`. then typed one text box, then click the submit button. the form can't be submitted.if i delete `return false` , the form can be submitted.

what's error maybe with my code?

Comment: Can you post your HTML? If `#edit-submit` is a button then you'll want to change that selector to be the ID of your form if you want to use `submit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is #edit-submit an input of type = "submit" or is it an input of type = "button"? here is how I would do it... make the input a type = "submit" and use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
  $({id of your form}).submit(function(){
    if($("#field-huima-0-value").val() == '' && $(".link-field .form-text").val() =='') {
      alert("you must at least enter one value！");
      return false;
    } else return true;
  });

});
```

Try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: you're right. it's ok. but i don't know why should add else return true; thank you.

Comment: you technically don't have to add the return true; but, it can't hurt

Comment: `else return true` isn't necessary for the submit handler.

Comment: i am not using the submit handler on the above example. i used click handler.i don'konw why the form can't be submitted. if i don't add theelse return true code.

Answer (score 1):

There *shouldn't* be any problem with what you're trying to do, although it sounds like you're mixing up your event handlers.

**You have two options...**

**Option 1**
Change the `edit-submit` selector to be the selector of your form, and use `submit` : [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/t8hxY/).

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    if ($("#field-huima-0-value").val() === '' 
        && $(".link-field .form-text").val() === '') {

        alert("you must at least enter one value!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Option 2**
Leave it as it is (using the button and `click` event) and explicitly call the form's `submit` function : [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/dK2eJ/).

```
$("#edit-submit").click(function() {
    if ($("#field-huima-0-value").val() === '' 
        && $(".link-field .form-text").val() === '') {

        alert("you must at least enter one value!");
        return false;
    }
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

**EDIT:** if you have `type="submit"` for your button then you don't need to explicitly submit the form. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/tdcbd/).